# How can I use 2 MultipleBorders option in GemBox

Tags: c#, .net, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I can use an inside border line style and an outside line style, but I don't know how I can use both.

As in this picture:

[image: Excel borders]

I am using C# and GemBox.Spreadsheet

```cs
//inside border
for (int line = 0; line < Projectsource.Count(); line++) //바깥border과 안쪽 얇은 border 같이 쓰면 안됨
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)//안쪽 cell border 얇게
    {
        worksheet.Cells[line, j].Style.Borders.SetBorders(
            MultipleBorders.Outside, SpreadsheetColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0), LineStyle.Thin);
    }
}

//outside border
//style.Borders.SetBorders(
//    MultipleBorders.Outside, SpreadsheetColor.FromArgb(140, 120, 50), LineStyle.Thick);//바깥쪽 border 두껍게 성공

worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A2:N762").Style = style;
```

Comment: Could you please add more details to your questions. Its not obvious on what exactly you are trying to solve. TY.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`MultipleBorders`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/T_GemBox_Spreadsheet_MultipleBorders.htm) is a flag enum which means that you can use bitwise operators with it.

So, here is how you can set both inside and outside borders with the newer versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet:

```
worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A2:N762").Style.Borders.SetBorders(
    MultipleBorders.Inside | MultipleBorders.Outside,
    SpreadsheetColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0),
    LineStyle.Thin);
```

Or you could use this instead:

```
worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A2:N762").Style.Borders.SetBorders(
    MultipleBorders.All,
    SpreadsheetColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0),
    LineStyle.Thin);
```

However, as you already noticed that older version (GemBox.Spreadsheet 3.9) doesn't have `MultipleBorders.Inside`. Also, even though it does have `MultipleBorders.All`, the behavior is different.

Nevertheless, here is how to set the desired borders with those older versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet:

```
foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A2:N762"))
    cell.Style.Borders.SetBorders(
        MultipleBorders.Outside,
        SpreadsheetColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0),
        LineStyle.Thin);
```

Answer (score 0):

my gembox version: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCM0L.png)

so nothing MultipleBorders.inside method in my gembox version
only have MultipleBorders.outside method